# is it correct to configure virtualenv in that location (manjaro)

Tags: package-management, packer

I'm using the "Vanessa" manjaro system.

I need to use virtualenv but it is not starting to create the environment.export.
I'm following this very common pattern on linux-based systems.
**sudo nano ~/.bashrc**

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

**all files are in that location**

**ls /usr/bin/vi**

```
vi@                         virtualenv*                 virtualenvwrapper.sh*     
view@                       virtualenv3*                visualinfo*               
vigr@                       virtualenv-clone*           visudo*                   
vipw*                       virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh*
```

but nothing happens, the script does not start and the **workon** command does not appear